# Error tls_process_server_certificate certificate verify failed when building against my own OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, certificate

I have a some application code which successfully creates an ssl link (via some 3rd party websockets code) when I use the system wide openssl (via sudo apt-get).

We also have openssl built as part of our cross platform development environment, and when I link against that I get the certificate error in the title.

Version 1.1.1f is the system one and I have tried building 1.1.1t (stable) and 1.1.1f so it's not a "version" thing.

I build openssl with:
../config --prefix=/linux shared -fPIC
make
sudo make install_sw

I have used this built version on a few projects successfully so I must be missing something subtle as to why it suffers from the validation of the server certificate, possibly some config or permissions to allow it access to a cert store????

Googling throws up mainly "the cert chain must have expired" but that's obviously not the case as the system wide openssl works.

Any help appreciated

Comment: So I'm half way there, the system version has symlinks, certs -> /etc/ssl/certs and openssl.cnf -> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.  When I set my development openssl with those symlinks it works, but how do I prevent my application when deployed to target machines from needing openssl to be in the location it is in my dev environment

Comment: Well I think I answered my own question, the environment var SSL_CERT_DIR controls where the certs are, so I guess regardless where my app builds against openssl is irrelevant and setting that var is the only way of controlling exactly where the runtime certs are